# Optimization of electricity costs

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I have to solve this exercise for the school and I do not really understand why the teacher solved it like this.

Here is the exercise:

I want to replace the 60 watt bulbs with 8 watt LED lamps. The 8 Watt LED lamps cost 16$ apiece.

After how many months are the costs for one lamp paid when the electricity price is 26 Ct/kWH and the lamp works 4 hours a day?

The solution is here.

```
P1 = 60 W / 1000 = 0,06 kW
P2 = 8w / 1000 = 0,008 kW
P3 = 0,06 kW - 0,008 kW = 0,052 kW

W = 0,052 kW * 4 Hours = 0,208 kWh
Price/Day = 0,208 kWh * 26 Ct/kWh = 5,408 Ct
Total_Days= 1600 Ct / 5,408 Ct = 296,3 Days
Total_Months = 296,3 / 30 = 9,8 Months
```

Does anybody show me another solutions to solve this? A solution that I would better understand.
I do not understood why he did the P3. Is not there another possibility to solvet this?

P.S. : Sorry for my english, I tried to translate this as best I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a 60 Watt Bulb, and a 8 Watt Bulb.
Now let's let them shine for an hour, and see how expencive that was:

$$ C_1 =  \frac{60}{1000}kW\cdot 26\frac{ct}{kWH} = 1.56 \ \frac{ct}{H} $$

That's not really cheap! Just saying. Anyway lets calculate the other Bulb:

$$ C_2 = \frac{8}{1000}kW\cdot 26\frac{ct}{kWH} = 0.208 \ \frac{ct}{H} $$

So basically for the first you pay $C_1$ per hour and for the second you pay $C_2$ per hour.
So if you want to calculate how much money you safe per hour it will be:
$$ C_3 = C_1-C_2 = 1.352 \ \frac{ct}{H}$$
So defnitly use the second. Only problem now is you have to buy the second bulb. 16$ not that cheap. 
So the real question is how long will it take till you safed enought money to buy the LED bulb?

$$ \frac{16$*100}{C_3} = \frac{1600\ ct}{1.352 \ \frac{ct}{H}} = 1183.431\  H$$
So you would have to use your new bulb for $1183.431\ H$. For you use it $4 \ H$ a day, you would need:

$$ T = \frac{1183.431 \ H}{4 \frac{H}{day}} = 296.3\ days$$

If you really think about this, I did exactly the same way just calculate in different measurements! So what is $P_3$? It is the electricity or Watts you safe per hour, if you would use the second and not the first light bulb. So its exactly like $C_3$ but I calculated the Price and your teacher the electricity!

One Hint: Always calculate in the units that are most easy to understand!

Comment: you mean C3 = C1 - C2 = 1.352

Comment: thank you mjb4! it's a good explanation!

Comment: Indeed I did! thx

Answer (score 0):

`P1` is the number of kilowatts used by a 60 watt bulb.  `P2` is the number of kilowatts used by an 8 watt bulb.  `P3` is the kilowatts saved by using an 8 watt bulb instead of a 60 watt bulb:

> P3 = P1 - P2 = 0,052 kW

Multiply it by 4 hours and you get the number of kilowatts saved per day:

> W = 0,052 kW * 4 Hours = 0,208 kWh

Multiply it times the cost per kWh and you get the money saved per day:

> Price/Day = 0,208 kWh * 26 Ct/kWh = 5,408 Ct

Divide the cost of the new bulb by the money saved per day and you get the number of days to recoup the cost of purchasing the LED:

> Total_Days= 1600 Ct / 5,408 Ct = 296,3 Days

Does that help?  It's not a different way of solving the problem, because in my opinion this is the most straight forward and easy way to solve it.  I just tried to explain what was happening in each step of your teacher's solution.

Comment: thank you! you helped me alot